# Grouping buttons together with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I use JQUERY in my ASP.NET MVC application for better user experience. I wonder if it is possible to group buttons together? Not option buttons but simple buttons. For example: is it possible to have buttonA + buttonB + buttonC grouped together followed by some spaces followed bu buttonD + buttonE + buttonF grouped together?  Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Bronzato: Do you mean visible grouping or logical grouping? Do you want to see it, or do they have the same behaviour? Is this jQuery or just Html?

Comment: @Marnix: I mean visible grouping. I would like to have some buttons with no pixels between them (like the Gmail toolbar).

Comment: This is more a css issue then not js

Comment: check out buttonset http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#toolbar on jquerys website

Comment: +1 @marnix what a beautiful question :) I assumed he meant visual lol :)

Comment: @Bronzato: I still think your are looking for floating li's. Can you comment on my answer for why it's not what you're looking for?

Comment: @Val: Thank you for your response. It successfully solved my problem. I'm not able to mark your answer as correct because yesterday I was connected as guest and now today I created a login in StackOverflow!?

Comment: @Bronzato: Do you own 2 accounts? Maybe try asking for some support on merging your accounts.

Comment: @Bronzato its ok you are welcome, you should post a comment instead of an answer coz it misleads other people :) thinking its an answer as here we all help each other kinda thing, and you can go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ to ask for help with your account I think but do read about pages of sister websites to find the right one

Comment: @Bronzato - I've merged your two accounts, so you should now be able to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a tool bar this http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#toolbar link should be very helpful for you...

Also its useful if you have themes on your website ;)

**html**

```
<div class="group">
   <button>Button A</button>
   <button>Button B</button>
</div>
<div class="group">
   <button>Button C</button>
   <button>Button D</button>
</div>
```

**js**

```
`$('.group').buttonset();`
```

**css**

```
.group{margin-right: 20px;float: left;}
```

also check a [demo](http://jsbin.com/aniye5/edit) here http://jsbin.com/aniye5/edit

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest. +1

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try asap and keep you in touch.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want some buttons to group and not use some fancy jQuery GUI, you can `float:left` a `ul` with `li` elements next to each other. Something that is done very often.

For example: Check this [website](http://www.queness.com/post/1513/14-outstanding-jquery-navigation-menu-tutorials) with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).